# React.js how do use the same page layout but different Data/information for personal information?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I trying to understand how react.js is working with help with react-router-dom. I have to face issues that I wanted to use the same layout for the personal detail form. but I want it to display different data for two different people. let say I click on "phua" and then it will use the layout and get the data from Data.js and provide the information, if I click on "foong" then the system will use the same layout but uses the data from foong in data.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css"
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/pages/HomePage/Home'
import Footer from './components/pages/Footer/Footer';
import Service from './components/Service';

import Info from './components/pages/Info/Info';


function App(){
  return(
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/service' exact component={Service}/>
        <Route path='/Information' component={Info/phua}/>
        <Route path='/Information' component={Info/foong}/>

      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
 

export default App;
```

Information.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./Information.css"
function Information({img, alt, name, age, gender}) {
    return (
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row_details">
                <div className="col-personal-logo"> 
                    <img src={img} alt={alt} className="personal-image"/>
                    <h2>Name:{name}</h2>
                    <p>Age:{age}</p>
                    <p>Gender:{gender}</p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>  
                <div className="col-personal">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Information
```

Data.js

```js
export const phua= {
    img:'images/dribbble-avatar.webp', 
    alt:'Phua',
    name:'Phua Yeong Tsann',
    age:'42', 
    gender:'Male',
}

export const foong= {
    img:'avatar_dribbble.webp', 
    alt:'Foong',
    name:'Foong',
    age:'32', 
    gender:'Female',
}
```

Info.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Information from '../../Information'
import {phua} from './Data'

function Info() {
    return (
        <>
            <Information {...phua} />
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Info
```

Comment: you can use `render` prop on the route instead of `component` and give it the `Information` component passing it the phua as a prop. Documentation [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func)

Comment: first of all, show the list of user data and on click get the specific personal data and pass that data to the Information component.

Comment: I still can't really understand how to do it. i try using render on App.js and its fail the system wont load

Comment: "Target container is not a DOM element" This error appear. i not sure whether I doing it correct